# get google coordinates by touching the map. iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps

How to get the coordinates by touching the map. Like i want to place a pin where I have tapped on the google map in iphone application.

Kindly explain me with an example.

Thanks,
Best Regards,
Naveed Butt

Comment: what are your thoughts about this?  what have you tried so far? what doesn't work?  why do you think it doesn't work? etc., etc., etc.  (send me teh codez is not what SO is for)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a draggable pin with the new sdk. Check this out [Map kit annotation](http://hollowout.blogspot.com/2009/07/mapkit-annotation-drag-and-drop-with.html)